# What is the data type of a single character in a string as an array?

Tags: c++, string

```
string s;
cin>>s;
```

suppose s = "stackoverflow"

now if we access `s[3]`, it should give out `'c'`

will `s[3]` be `'c'` or `"c"`?

as in will it be a char data type or string data type?

Comment: You can always check [the documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_at) to kow that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`std::string` is not a built-in type, so operator `[]` in `s[3]` is a call to a member function defining this operator in the string template.

You can find the type by looking up the [reference page for `operator []`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_at):

> Returns a reference to the character at specified location pos.

To look up the type `reference` and `const_reference` from the documentation see "member types" section of [`std::basic_string<CharT>` template.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string)

If you are looking for `std::string` of length 1 starting at location 3, use `substr` instead:

```
s.substr(3, 1); // This produces std::string containing "c"
```

Comment: Perhaps you could also explain how to look up the return type "`reference`" in the parent page and untangle the template usage to finally get "`char&`".

Comment: @aschepler Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

It returns reference to the character as the operator `[]` is overloaded for `std::string`

```
char& operator[] (size_t pos);
const char& operator[] (size_t pos) const;
```

> will s[3] be 'c' or "c"?

Character 'c', not string "c".

Answer (score 1):

It is easiest to remember that `std::string` is not a native type like `char` is, but a wrapper `class` that contains an array of `chars` to form a string.

`std::string` simply overloads the C array operator [] to return the `char` at a given index, hence:

> will `s[3]` be `'c'` or `"c"`?
>
> Answer: `'c'`